# Hyperlink in peoplesoft is peoplecode command or URL Identifier command

Tags: peoplesoft

How to know whether the Push Button/Hyperlink properties indicate that the Hyperlink destination is a PeopleCode Command? Is it something related to external link static and dynamic? what does static and dynamic say here?

Comment: Give more details: print screen, tools version. It is not clear what you want... .my first response to you would suggest to go to peoplebooks to check the button def.

Answer (score 0):

A Push Button/Hyperlink on a Page has a "Destination" (just double-click the field in Application Designer) property which needs to be set to "PeopleCode Command" in order to execute a FieldChange Event.

There are other types of Destinations (which I think is what you were referring to) like "External Link" which can be Static (predefined from the URL Catalog) or Dynamic (set at runtime).